# Add seperate/new viewType within a recyclerView irrespective of its layoutManager in android

Tags: android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-viewholder

I am creating a layout with recyclerView having GridLayoutManager. i was able to achieve whole list in a particular adapter layout, but i want to have a button View within the list items as shown below. i tried to use multiple view Types in recyclerView Adapter but the button view is not shown as per design.

if anyone who could guide me how to achieve this particular design within a recyclerView, will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override the method setSpanSizeLookUp after initializing the adapter  and set span size in layoutManager. Follow the link for more, https://stackoverflow.com/a/37525577/13416773